# PHP form not posting

Tags: php, mysql, http-post

This form is not posting values at all and I can't figure out. I have tried using both PHP_SELF and a separate page action but nothing works. All other forms work - so its not a server issue. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
 <form name=\"projects\" action=\"upload.php\" method=\"POST\">

    <?php 
        echo "<tr>
            <td valign = \"top\" bgcolor=\"$row_color\"> $title </td> 
            <td valign = \"top\" bgcolor=\"$row_color\"> $description </td> 
            <td valign = \"top\" bgcolor=\"$row_color\"> $academicdiscipline </td>
            <td valign = \"top\" bgcolor=\"$row_color\"> "; 

                $allowed = $academicdiscipline; 
                switch ($allowed) {
                case "Civil and Environmental": 
                  echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                          <option>  </option>
                          <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
                          <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
                          <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
                          <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
                          <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
                          <option value=\"6\"> 6 </option>
                          <option value=\"7\"> 7 </option>
                          <option value=\"8\"> 8 </option>
                          <option value=\"9\"> 9 </option>
                          <option value=\"10\"> 10 </option>
                        </select> ";
                  break;
                case "Electronics": 
                  echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                          <option>  </option>
                          <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
                          <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
                          <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
                          <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
                          <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
                        </select>";
                  break;
                case "Environment and Management": 
                  echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                          <option>  </option>
                          <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
                          <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
                          <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
                          <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
                          <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
                        </select>";
                  break;
                case "Mechanical and Materials": 
                  echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                          <option>  </option>
                          <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
                          <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
                          <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
                          <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
                          <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
                          <option value=\"6\"> 6 </option>
                          <option value=\"7\"> 7 </option>
                          <option value=\"8\"> 8 </option>
                          <option value=\"9\"> 9 </option>
                          <option value=\"10\"> 10 </option>
                          <option value=\"11\"> 11 </option>
                          <option value=\"12\"> 12 </option>
                          <option value=\"13\"> 13 </option> 
                          <option value=\"14\"> 14 </option>
                          <option value=\"15\"> 15 </option>
                        </select> ";
                  break;
                default: 
                    echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                          <option>  </option>
                          <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
                          <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
                          <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
                          <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
                          <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
                        </select> ";
                  break;
                default: 
                    echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
                              <option>  </option>
                              <option> 1 </option>
                              <option> 2 </option>
                              <option> 3 </option> 
                              <option> 4 </option>
                              <option> 5 </option>
                            </select>"; } 


            echo "</td></tr>
         <tr bgcolor=\"#ffffff\"> </tr>
         <tr bgcolor=\"#902C2E\"> </tr>"; 

      $row_count++; }  

 echo"<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><input name=\"reset\" type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\"/> 
       <input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Select\"/> 
</tr></table>" ;  ?>
</form>
```

The upload.php page can upload all other entries but the priorities, which I can't get to POST from the code above. This is the upload.php file:

```
if(isset($_POST[submit]) && !empty($_POST[submit])) { 

$fullname = ''.$data[0]["sn"][0].', '.$data[0]["givenname"][0].'';  
$givenname = ''.$data[0]["givenname"][0].''; 
$priority = '$_POST[priority]'; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM flux_student_records WHERE studentname = '$fullname' ";
$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  

 if (!$retval) { 
        die('Could not retrieve data: There are no project proposals yet. <br /><br /> ' . mysql_error());   }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) { 
        extract($row);  }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection( id, studentname, title, academicdiscipline, priority)
            SELECT flux_student_records.id, flux_student_records.studentname, project_proposals.title, project_proposals.academicdiscipline, '$priority'
            FROM project_proposals
            JOIN flux_student_records ON project_proposals.academicdiscipline = flux_student_records.academicdiscipline
            WHERE flux_student_records.studentname = '$studentname'
            AND 'priority' IS NOT NULL
            LIMIT 5"; 

    $retval = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: MySQL query failed. Project has not been added to the database. '); 

echo "<p> Your project selection have been added to the system. <br> You'll be redirected to list of projects in the system. </p><br />";   
//echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=2;url=index.php>";


}
```

Comment: You need to surround your array keys in quotes, like `$_POST['submit']`.

Comment: `$priority = '$_POST[priority]'; ` that is assigning the exact string `'$_POST[priority]'` to that variable.

Comment: Thanks Jessica. Tried $priority = $_POST['priority']; as well and that doesn't work either.

Comment: why do you have a switch case? your code has too many problems

Answer (score 5):

Far as I can tell from your posted code in your question, you're not in PHP with

```
<form name=\"projects\" action=\"upload.php\" method=\"POST\">
```

so remove the slashes `\` from all of those.

Then these:

```
if(isset($_POST[submit]) && !empty($_POST[submit])) { 

$priority = '$_POST[priority]';
```

you need to add and remove quotes:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) { 

$priority = $_POST['priority'];
```

Also, all your `<option>`'s have no values set for them, so you may want to do something about that.

I.e.: `<option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>`

etc.

Plus, drop using `mysql_` functions. They're deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). *They're much safer.*

---

> *I have tried using both PHP_SELF...*

You can use `action=""` if NOT inside PHP, which does the same as self. Or, `action=\"\"` if inside PHP, or `action=''` depending on how you're echoing it.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:**

Another thing I noticed in your query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO flux_project_selection( id, studentname, title, academicdiscipline, priority)
        SELECT flux_student_records.id, flux_student_records.studentname, project_proposals.title, project_proposals.academicdiscipline, '$priority'
        FROM project_proposals
        JOIN flux_student_records ON project_proposals.academicdiscipline = flux_student_records.academicdiscipline
        WHERE flux_student_records.studentname = '$studentname'
        AND 'priority' IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 5";
```

Try removing the quotes from `'$priority'` and from `AND 'priority'` since that looks to be a column.

If `$priority` contains any characters that MySQL may complain about, then wrap it in ticks and not quotes and escaping the variable using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

I.e.:

```
project_proposals.academicdiscipline, `$priority`
            FROM project_proposals

...

AND `priority` IS NOT NULL
```

This does not help you also

```
$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: MySQL query failed. Project has not been added to the database. ');
```

use `or die(mysql_error());` instead of `or die('Error: MySQL query failed. Project has not been added to the database. ');`

Comment: Sidenote: My answer was not based on comments posted. I was busy typing all of this up. It takes a bit of time ;-)

Comment: @NoooSmyth You're welcome, but you need to tell me why it's not working and if you're getting errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @NoooSmyth also, this line does not help you `$retval = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: MySQL query failed. Project has not been added to the database. ');` do ``or die(mysql_error());``

Comment: @NoooSmyth you also seem to be missing some code. `$fullname` seems undefined and is not mentioned anywhere else in your code/question.

Comment: Now I'm getting errors: Notice: Undefined variable: error in /tron/top2/eng-project/student/uploadprojectselection.php on line 147

Comment: I've defined $fullname, etc. It inserts everything I need into the databse apart from the priority, which doesn't seem to be posting from the previous page at all.    
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) { 

 $fullname = ''.$data[0]["sn"][0].', '.$data[0]["givenname"][0].'';  
 $givenname = ''.$data[0]["givenname"][0].''; 
 //$priority = '$_POST[priority]'; 
 $priority = $_POST['priority'];

Comment: @NoooSmyth then you will need to go over your entire code, the ones you didn't post and figure out where that `error` variable isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry figuring out how stackoverflow works - keeps posting comments before i'm done writing them. The problem seem to be with $priority - which I think I have defined.

Comment: @NoooSmyth No worries. I've noticed something else in your code; in your query. Reload my answer and look near the end under **Edit:

Another thing I noticed in your query:**. That could be the fault, or playing a major part in your code's failure.

Comment: `or die(mysql_error());` helps. But removing quotes indicate errors in sql syntax when when escaping the variable. The same syntax works ok in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @NoooSmyth what is the value of `$priority = $_POST['priority'];`? what do you enter in there for it?

Comment: The values are selected from a dropbox, numbers 1-10.

Comment: @NoooSmyth your `<option>` tags as I stated, have no values for it, so nothing will come of it. As stated in my answer with an example.

Comment: All options now have values. Still won't work. `echo "<select name=\"priority\" class=\"priority\">
         <option>  </option>
         <option value=\"1\"> 1 </option>
         <option value=\"2\"> 2 </option>
         <option value=\"3\"> 3 </option> 
         <option value=\"4\"> 4 </option>
         <option value=\"5\"> 5 </option>
         <option value=\"6\"> 6 </option>
         <option value=\"7\"> 7 </option>
         <option value=\"8\"> 8 </option>
         <option value=\"9\"> 9 </option>
         <option value=\"10\"> 10 </option>
       </select> ";`

Comment: @NoooSmyth make sure that your db's column type corresponds to those numbers. This is getting far too complicated at this point. I suggest you make up another file with a smaller version with 1 or 2 inputs/values. Once you've gotten that to work, then build on it. Those values are numeric, therefore your column type and length may be a factor here. Such as `int(10)` as an example. I don't know what else I can do here to help resolve this; I'm out of ideas/options.

Comment: Thanks very much Fred -ii-. Will try from beginning and hopefully should work.

Answer (score 1):

edit

`<form name=\"projects\" action=\"upload.php\" method=\"POST\">`

to

`<form name="projects" action="upload.php" method="POST">`

or put it inside the echo

also

`$priority = '$_POST[priority]';`

this will put `$_POST[priority]` as a string  in the variable `$priority`

change it to this:

`$priority = $_POST['priority'];`

Comment: Thanks Ehad Eldeeb. I've been trying the same thing for a while. Doesn't work.